# Making Video Games In pure Java, where to go?

Tags: java, swing, resources, awt

I have been programing for about a year now, and have a very good grasp on all the basic of programming in generaly and am a pretty decent Java programmer, so now that I have the time I would like to start making games in Java. However, Id really like to not use any extra librarries, and just use pure Java for the first little bit until I fully understand the machanics of a video game.

I have been looking around the internet and have seen more "best ways" to do this than I can count. So if somebody could point me in the right direction that would be great! (As in send me to the best, easiest to follow, and most up to date ressource either print or on the web)

It just seems that no matter where I look I get completly diffrent info on the same subjuct. So I would really apreciate if somebody could just give me a resource that follows whatever the current standard is.
P.s typed on my phone so sorry for any typos :-)

Comment: I like the question, but it's probably not well suited for this site.  It might be better asked at [Programmers Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: *However, Id really like to not use any extra librarries, and just use pure Java for the first little bit until I fully understand the machanics of a video game* Check out [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/444547/game-development-loop-logic-and-collision-detection-java-swing-2d) thread I posted which is a very basic Game Library I created (by library I mean it has classes etc which are easily re-usable and everything is written in pure java no extra 3rd party stuff) and of course I applied by knowledge of java best practices.